# Is if statement over complicated?

Tags: c++, vector

This is the part that brakes, `zod1` `zod2` `zodA` are vectors. In vectors I store `int`. Cant tell why it crashes cause it gives no error

```
if(zod1[u]+zod2[y]==zodA[t] || (zod1[u]+zod2[y])%10==zodA[t])
```

Questions:
1 Is if statement over complicated
2 Can I use vectors like that for solving math in if statement (sorry can't explain better)
3 If 2 question is true how should I solve it

Explanations: 
variable names are in my own language (sorry if it looks weird) 
Values are zero for all (ex zod1[u]=0)
added whole function (variables going to the function are passed correctly and I know I use some unnecessary thing)

```
void calc(vector<char> zodis1, vector<char> zodis2, vector<char> zodisAts,int zo1,int zo2,int zoA)
{int i,keliamas=0;
int k =0;
   vector<int> zod1(0);
   vector<int> zod2(0);
   vector<int> zodA(0);
   for(i=0;i<zodis1.size();i++)
   {
       zod1.push_back(0);
   }
      for(i=0;i<zodis2.size();i++)
   {
       zod2.push_back(0);
   }
      for(i=0;i<zodisAts.size();i++)
   {
       zod2.push_back(0);
   }
int   u=zodis1.size()-1;
int   y=zodis2.size()-1;
int  t=zodisAts.size()-1;

   if(zod1[u]+zod2[y]==zodA[t] || (zod1[u]+zod2[y])%10==zodA[t])
    {//if((zod1[u]+zod2[y])/10==1)
    {
        keliamas=1;
    }
     if(u==0||y==0||t!=0)
      {
         if(keliamas==1)
         {


         }
      }
        u--;
        y--;
        t--;

    }
   else
    {if(zod1[u]!=9)
        zod1[u]=zod1[u]+1;
     else
     {  if(u!=zodis1.size()-1)
         u++;
        else
        {
            cout<<"something wrong man";
        }
     }

    }
}
```

Comment: 1. Opinion based. To me it's not, for many others it probably is.  2. and 3. What the heck do you mean? In math, do you solve anything with just conditionals? I highly doubt it. It's like asking question "Can I solve anything by asking >if k is even<?"

Comment: What are the values of the variables when it crashes? What is the stack trace?

Comment: Q1 is salvageable: "is there an equivalent expression which is less complex?".

Comment: explain first and 2 and 3 yeah sorry don't know how to explain it but if works if(a!=b) etc can I use it as if(a+b+c==a) with vectors?

Comment: It's not really complex, but the variable names make little sense (to me). Maybe introducing new variables for `zod1[u]` and so on would make it more readable.

Comment: A little whitespace wouldn't go amiss.

Comment: We need more code, before the line shown, to understand where is your error. How many items are in each vector ? What are the values of the index variables ? And so on...

Comment: Either this is a really bizarre way of asking "Why does this code crash", or I have no idea what this question is about

Comment: Matt McNabb Yes thats the question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

EDIT:
Error is here:

```
   for(i=0;i<zodisAts.size();i++)
   {
       zod2.push_back(0); // should be zodA
   }
```

> Is if statement over complicated

No, I think it is very simple with just one 'or'. However, if `zodA[t]` is always less than 10, then your if condition can be written as:

```
if ( (zod1[u]+zod2[y])%10==zodA[t] )
```

> Can I use vectors like that for solving math in if statement (sorry
>   can't explain better)

Yes you can.

> If 2 question is true how should I solve it

If it compiles but then crashes, then probably you are accessing out of bounds indices. Check that your indices are less than the vector sizes.

Comment: Thanks man! Rookie mistake :)